# How to provide class with multiline element gutenberg RichText block?

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm using following code for gutenberg RichText block

```
el(
    RichText,
    {
        key: 'editable',
        tagName: 'ul',
        multiline: 'li',
        className: 'list-group',
        onChange: onChangeContent,
        value: content,
    }
)
```

Can anyone help me how to assign a class `list-item` with multiline li element?

Comment: Would also like to know this.

Comment: Would also like to know this too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think gutenberg supports this out of the box. You can modify the content of the rich text editor by replacing the `<li>` with `<li class="list-item">` in the save function.
You need to make use of [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) to render string as html inside `<ul>`

```
save: function save(props) {
    function createMarkup() {
        return { __html: props.attributes.content.replace(/<li>/g, '<li class="list-item">') };
    }

    return el('ul', { dangerouslySetInnerHTML: createMarkup() });
}
```

**UPDATED** 
If you need to do this immediately when you add a new `<li>` in the editor itself, then you need to call a function to add the class to the `<li>` elements in the onChange event of the RichText component.

```
edit: function edit(props) {
    function setCustomClass() {
        $('.list-group li').addClass('list-item');
    }
    return el(RichText, {
        key: 'editable',
        tagName: 'ul',
        multiline: 'li',
        className: 'list-group',
        onChange: function onChangeContent(content) {
            props.setAttributes({ content: content });
            setCustomClass();
        },
        value: props.attributes.content
    });
},
```

Comment: Well, it will not work promptly. It will work after saving the document. I need to add that class whenever a new li element is added into the list.

Comment: I've changed the answer to include the change whenever a new li is added @RameezIqbal